# Передача данных через Intent

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, android-intent, android-notification

У меня есть Notification с action button, для которой я создаю следующий Intent с данными для BroadcastReceiver

```
    Intent rIntent = new Intent(context, Receiver.class);
    rIntent.setAction(ACTION_CLICK);

    rIntent.putExtra(TASK_TYPE2_EXTRA, task.getTaskType());
    rIntent.putExtra(TASK_UUID2_EXTRA, task.getId());
    PendingIntent clickPIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, rIntent, 0);
```

Но когда Intent доходит до BroadcastReceiver, в нем нет никаких данных, в чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Попробуйте флаг `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` в качестве последнего параметра в методе `getBroadcast`.

Comment: @eugeneek Спасибо, это помогло !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете некорректный флаг для `PendingIntent`а (последний параметр). Используйте, например `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`:

```
PendingIntent clickPIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context, 1, rIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

P.S. Хорошей практикой является всегда использовать константы, вместо хардкода значений (второй параметр в вашем примере - `int requestCode`). Исключается вероятность опечатки.